# Different ranges - defferent iteration rate?

Tags: python, iterator, range, iteration

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
from little_lib import *

points = []
k_step = 0.001

#for k_i in np.arange(1.0,4.0, k_step):
for i in range (1000, 4000):
    k_i = i*k_step
    print k_i 
    m1 = model( 0.3, k_i ) 
    statList = m1.getStatList()
    for s in statList:
        points.append ((k_i,s)) 

plt.scatter(*zip(*points), marker='.', s = 0.5)
plt.show()
```

I noticed that if I use `np.arange(1., 4., k_step)` it iterates slower than if I use default `range(1000, 4000)`. Why is it so and how can I use advantage of python to solve this without using unpythonic `k_i = i*k_step`?

Comment: Are you on python2.x or python3.x?

Comment: Numpy arange is more suitable for vectorized operations not for loops.

Comment: U can use range(1.0,4.0,k_step).

Comment: No. I can't. Because of `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got float.`